# Password protect a generated PDF from page

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I'm currently using PHP  for retrieving data and the JavaScript print function for my inventory reports and my staff saves it in pdf form. This is the sample output:

[image]

Everything works perfectly but I have a security issue. I want my staff to not be able to open the pdf, thus securing it with a password.

Is there, by any chance, a way to do this? Like whenever they click a button, instead of the print dialog box (ctrl+ P) opening, it will directly open a save to dialog box and it will automatically have a password so that I can be the only one who can view and print it.

Or is there a PDF library for this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a library and it works as expected.

http://www.html2pdf.fr/en/download